# Model Data Field Label not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code. I'm trying to display the label of the field with LabelFor, but this isn't working.

In my Model

```
    [Display(Name = "Tour Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormatAttribute(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime TourBeginDate { get; set; }
```

and

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.TourBeginDate) %>
```

but I'm getting:

```
<label for="TourBeginDate">TourBeginDate</label>
```

instead of

```
<label for="TourBeginDate">Tour Start Date</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want to use is

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.TourBeginDate) %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed. That's the one I used. Very odd.

Comment: @Dean: Is the label in definition in the model you are using for displaying?

Comment: I'd like to display the content within: [Display(Name = "Tour Start Date")]

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for Display property is:

```
DisplayName("Tour Start Date")
```